“Never asked” or “never asked her”?

Is she a lesbian?
I do not know. Never asked.
I do not know. Never asked her.

Which one is better?

askled is not a word ... looks like you have two sentences run into one ... please add correct punctuation

Better for what purpose? More grammatical/"correct"? More idiomatic? Easier to understand? Quicker to say? Whether it's idiomatic will probably depend on location, age, formality, etc.

If you're going to give a clipped, curt reply like "Never asked" you wouldn't say "I do not know" but "I don't know" or simply "Don't know".   Don't know. Never asked.  That is informal, conversational, and quite abrupt, and it could express that you are rejecting the question. It might be interpreted that way by the listener.

I've seen her extensive collection of Judy Garland posters.

In casual speech, you sometimes drop words such as "I" or "her".  There's not much point in asking "which is better"; what do you mean by "better".  Both are grammatically incomplete.
The full sentence is "I have never asked her."  But you could drop the subject, verb, and object of "asked" in casual speech.
But in casual speech, you would not say "I do not know".  You could drop "I" and contract "do not" to "Don't know", which would be pronounced as "Dunno"

I could mean I never asked anyone (e.g. people who know her)_.
